# android native function from sub class unsatisfied linker error

Tags: android, android-ndk, unsatisfiedlinkerror

Hi had worked many native called, but are all from classes not from subclasses!

In a nutshell, i have a native method in `private static class VideoRender
        implements GLSurfaceView.Renderer` which is a subclass inside `VideoActivity`

The native method is giving `unsatisfied Linker error` for the native declaration of the function 
`int Java_com_MyFoo_VideoActivity_VideoRender_nativeInit(...)`

Please help in solving this! Many examples shows how to use native method from classes, but i want to use it from a subclass

Answer (score 0):

If I'm not mistaken, the right name to give your native function would be:

```
Java_com_MyFoo_VideoActivity$VideoRender_nativeInit(...)
```

This corresponds to the way Java "compiles" subclasses: look into your `VideoActivity.class` file, and you'll see that the `VideoRender` subclass is probably stored under `VideoActivity$VideoRender`.

Comment: on looking at the error logs, i also tried this, but still same response:(

Comment: Hmmm... maybe you should try `Java_com_MyFoo_VideoActivity_00024VideoRender_nativeInit`, as explained [here](https://community.oracle.com/message/6481452#6481452).